# Как настроить background-color для кнопок слайдера?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, slick.js

Здравствуйте. Суть проблемы такова: есть слайдер на Slick.js, у которого шесть слайдов. Необходимо настроить background-color каждой кнопки так, чтобы при клике на кнопку, у нее отображался свой цвет фона => у каждой кнопки свой цвет фона.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.mobile-slider').slick({
    slidesToShow: 1,
    dots: true,
    mobileFirst: true,
    arrows: false
  });
});
```

```css
.mobile-slider {
 display: block;
 height: 90vh; } }

.mobile-slider .mobile-slide {
width: 100vw;
height: 90vh;
background-size: cover;
background-position: 50% 50%;
display: -webkit-box;
display: flex;
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
-webkit-box-direction: normal;
flex-direction: column; }

.mobile-slider .mobile-slide .mobile-inline {
display: -webkit-inline-box;
display: inline-flex;
margin-left: 5vw;
margin-right: 5vw; }

.mobile-slider .mobile-slide .mobile-inline margin-top 35vh h1 {
color: #fff; }

.mobile-slider .mobile-slide h1 {
font-family: 'Adineue';
color: #fff; }

.mobile-slider .mobile-slide p {
font-family: 'Lato';
color: #fff;
display: -webkit-inline-box;
display: inline-flex;
margin-left: 5vw;
margin-right: 20vw; }

.mobile-slider .mobile-slide .mobile-inline-bottom {
display: -webkit-inline-box;
display: inline-flex;
-webkit-box-align: center;
align-items: center; }

.mobile-slider .mobile-slide .mobile-inline-bottom p {
font-family: 'Adineue'; }

.mobile-slider .mobile-slide-roof {
background-image: url('http://new.rofas.kz/images/roof-bg.png'); }

.mobile-slider .mobile-slide-roof .mobile-inline-bottom p {
margin-right: 2vw;
color: #e64e4e; }

.mobile-slider .mobile-slide-fasad {
background-image: url('http://new.rofas.kz/images/fasad-bg.png'); }

.mobile-slider .mobile-slide-fasad .mobile-inline-bottom p {
margin-right: 2vw;
color: #f7a550; }

.mobile-slider .mobile-slide-design {
background-image: url('http://new.rofas.kz/images/design-bg.png'); }

.mobile-slider .mobile-slide-design .mobile-inline-bottom p {
margin-right: 2vw;
color: #fedd32; }

.mobile-slider .mobile-slide-industry {
background-image: url('http://new.rofas.kz/images/industry-bg.png'); }

.mobile-slider .mobile-slide-industry .mobile-inline-bottom p {
margin-right: 2vw;
color: #51b9f1; }

.mobile-slider .mobile-slide-eco {
background-image: url('http://new.rofas.kz/images/eco-bg.png'); }

.mobile-slider .mobile-slide-eco .mobile-inline-bottom p {
margin-right: 2vw;
color: #70ca57; }

.mobile-slider .mobile-slide-stone {
background-image: url('http://new.rofas.kz/images/stone-bg.png'); }

.mobile-slider .mobile-slide-stone .mobile-inline-bottom p {
margin-right: 2vw;
color: #956ccc; }

.slick-dots {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  flex-direction: column;
  z-index: 1;
  position: fixed;
  top: 12vh;
  right: 8vw;
  list-style: none;
}

.slick-dots button {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  background-color: #000;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  color: #000;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  margin-bottom: 2vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="mobile-slider">
  <div class="mobile-slide mobile-slide-roof">
    <div class="mobile-inline" style="margin-top: 40vh">
      <h1>Rofas</h1>
      <h1 style="margin-left: 3vw; color: #e64e4e; font-family: 'ABold'">Roof</h1>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    <div class="mobile-inline-bottom">
      <p>Rofas Roof</p><img src="http://new.rofas.kz/icons/right-arrow-roof.png"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="mobile-slide mobile-slide-fasad">
    <div class="mobile-inline" style="margin-top: 40vh">
      <h1>Rofas</h1>
      <h1 style="margin-left: 3vw; color: #f7a550; font-family: 'ABold'">Facade</h1>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    <div class="mobile-inline-bottom">
      <p>Rofas Facade</p><img src="http://new.rofas.kz/icons/right-arrow-fasad.png"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="mobile-slide mobile-slide-design">
    <div class="mobile-inline" style="margin-top: 40vh">
      <h1>Rofas</h1>
      <h1 style="margin-left: 3vw; color: #fedd32; font-family: 'ABold'">Design</h1>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    <div class="mobile-inline-bottom">
      <p>Rofas Design</p><img src="http://new.rofas.kz/icons/right-arrow-design.png"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="mobile-slide mobile-slide-industry">
    <div class="mobile-inline" style="margin-top: 40vh">
      <h1>Rofas</h1>
      <h1 style="margin-left: 3vw; color: #51b9f1; font-family: 'ABold'">Industry</h1>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    <div class="mobile-inline-bottom">
      <p>Rofas Industry</p><img src="http://new.rofas.kz/icons/right-arrow-industry.png"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="mobile-slide mobile-slide-eco">
    <div class="mobile-inline" style="margin-top: 40vh">
      <h1>Rofas</h1>
      <h1 style="margin-left: 3vw; color: #70ca57; font-family: 'ABold'">Eco</h1>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    <div class="mobile-inline-bottom">
      <p>Rofas Industry</p><img src="http://new.rofas.kz/icons/right-arrow-eco.png"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="mobile-slide mobile-slide-stone">
    <div class="mobile-inline" style="margin-top: 40vh">
      <h1>Rofas</h1>
      <h1 style="margin-left: 3vw; color: #956ccc; font-family: 'ABold'">Stone</h1>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    <div class="mobile-inline-bottom">
      <p>Rofas Industry</p><img src="http://new.rofas.kz/icons/right-arrow-stone.png"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот реализация:

У каждого `div` с классом `mobile-slide` добавил атрибут `data-color`, и как видно из кодов слайдера `id` кликабельных кружочков записано в тот самый `div` в атрибуте `aria-describedby`, этим же они связаны, вот и добавил событие клик на кружочки и в нем взял атрибут `data-color` и вставил в `background` текущего кликнувшего элемента.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.mobile-slider').slick({
    slidesToShow: 1,
    dots: true,
    mobileFirst: true,
    arrows: false
  });
  $('.slick-dots>li').on('click', function(){
    var image_data = $(this).attr('id');
    var li_color = $('div[aria-describedby="'+image_data+'"]').data('color');
    $('.slick-dots>li>button').css({backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF'});
    $(this).find('button').css({backgroundColor: li_color});
  });
});
```

```css
.mobile-slider {
 display: block;
 height: 90vh; } }

.mobile-slider .mobile-slide {
width: 100vw;
height: 90vh;
background-size: cover;
background-position: 50% 50%;
display: -webkit-box;
display: flex;
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
-webkit-box-direction: normal;
flex-direction: column; }

.mobile-slider .mobile-slide .mobile-inline {
display: -webkit-inline-box;
display: inline-flex;
margin-left: 5vw;
margin-right: 5vw; }

.mobile-slider .mobile-slide .mobile-inline margin-top 35vh h1 {
color: #fff; }

.mobile-slider .mobile-slide h1 {
font-family: 'Adineue';
color: #fff; }

.mobile-slider .mobile-slide p {
font-family: 'Lato';
color: #fff;
display: -webkit-inline-box;
display: inline-flex;
margin-left: 5vw;
margin-right: 20vw; }

.mobile-slider .mobile-slide .mobile-inline-bottom {
display: -webkit-inline-box;
display: inline-flex;
-webkit-box-align: center;
align-items: center; }

.mobile-slider .mobile-slide .mobile-inline-bottom p {
font-family: 'Adineue'; }

.mobile-slider .mobile-slide-roof {
background-image: url('http://new.rofas.kz/images/roof-bg.png'); }

.mobile-slider .mobile-slide-roof .mobile-inline-bottom p {
margin-right: 2vw;
color: #e64e4e; }

.mobile-slider .mobile-slide-fasad {
background-image: url('http://new.rofas.kz/images/fasad-bg.png'); }

.mobile-slider .mobile-slide-fasad .mobile-inline-bottom p {
margin-right: 2vw;
color: #f7a550; }

.mobile-slider .mobile-slide-design {
background-image: url('http://new.rofas.kz/images/design-bg.png'); }

.mobile-slider .mobile-slide-design .mobile-inline-bottom p {
margin-right: 2vw;
color: #fedd32; }

.mobile-slider .mobile-slide-industry {
background-image: url('http://new.rofas.kz/images/industry-bg.png'); }

.mobile-slider .mobile-slide-industry .mobile-inline-bottom p {
margin-right: 2vw;
color: #51b9f1; }

.mobile-slider .mobile-slide-eco {
background-image: url('http://new.rofas.kz/images/eco-bg.png'); }

.mobile-slider .mobile-slide-eco .mobile-inline-bottom p {
margin-right: 2vw;
color: #70ca57; }

.mobile-slider .mobile-slide-stone {
background-image: url('http://new.rofas.kz/images/stone-bg.png'); }

.mobile-slider .mobile-slide-stone .mobile-inline-bottom p {
margin-right: 2vw;
color: #956ccc; }

.slick-dots {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  flex-direction: column;
  z-index: 1;
  position: fixed;
  top: 12vh;
  right: 8vw;
  list-style: none;
}

.slick-dots button {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  background-color: #000;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  color: #000;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  margin-bottom: 2vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="mobile-slider">
  <div class="mobile-slide mobile-slide-roof" data-color="#456789">
    <div class="mobile-inline" style="margin-top: 40vh">
      <h1>Rofas</h1>
      <h1 style="margin-left: 3vw; color: #e64e4e; font-family: 'ABold'">Roof</h1>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    <div class="mobile-inline-bottom">
      <p>Rofas Roof</p><img src="http://new.rofas.kz/icons/right-arrow-roof.png"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="mobile-slide mobile-slide-fasad" data-color="#456123">
    <div class="mobile-inline" style="margin-top: 40vh">
      <h1>Rofas</h1>
      <h1 style="margin-left: 3vw; color: #f7a550; font-family: 'ABold'">Facade</h1>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    <div class="mobile-inline-bottom">
      <p>Rofas Facade</p><img src="http://new.rofas.kz/icons/right-arrow-fasad.png"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="mobile-slide mobile-slide-design" data-color="#456705">
    <div class="mobile-inline" style="margin-top: 40vh">
      <h1>Rofas</h1>
      <h1 style="margin-left: 3vw; color: #fedd32; font-family: 'ABold'">Design</h1>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    <div class="mobile-inline-bottom">
      <p>Rofas Design</p><img src="http://new.rofas.kz/icons/right-arrow-design.png"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="mobile-slide mobile-slide-industry" data-color="#456789">
    <div class="mobile-inline" style="margin-top: 40vh">
      <h1>Rofas</h1>
      <h1 style="margin-left: 3vw; color: #51b9f1; font-family: 'ABold'">Industry</h1>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    <div class="mobile-inline-bottom">
      <p>Rofas Industry</p><img src="http://new.rofas.kz/icons/right-arrow-industry.png"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="mobile-slide mobile-slide-eco" data-color="#450089">
    <div class="mobile-inline" style="margin-top: 40vh">
      <h1>Rofas</h1>
      <h1 style="margin-left: 3vw; color: #70ca57; font-family: 'ABold'">Eco</h1>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    <div class="mobile-inline-bottom">
      <p>Rofas Industry</p><img src="http://new.rofas.kz/icons/right-arrow-eco.png"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="mobile-slide mobile-slide-stone" data-color="#006789">
    <div class="mobile-inline" style="margin-top: 40vh">
      <h1>Rofas</h1>
      <h1 style="margin-left: 3vw; color: #956ccc; font-family: 'ABold'">Stone</h1>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    <div class="mobile-inline-bottom">
      <p>Rofas Industry</p><img src="http://new.rofas.kz/icons/right-arrow-stone.png"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```